# Is there a homotopy coherent analogue of Dieudonné modules?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, hopf-algebras

Let $K$ be a perfect field with characteristic $>0$ and $\mathcal{H}$ the category of graded connected abelian hopf algebras over $K$.
By a theorem of Schoeller there is a canonical equivalence between $\mathcal{H}$ and the category of
Dieudonne modules over $K.$

> **Question.** Is there a homotopy-coherent version of Dieudonné modules and a homotopy-coherent version of Schoeller's theorem that
> identifies a derived version of Dieudonné module with a connected
> $E_\infty$-hopf algebra over $K$?

By definition, an $E_\infty$-hopf algebra over $K$ is an abelian group object (in the derived sense) in the $\infty$-category of $E_\infty$-coalgebras in the derived $\infty$-category of $K,$ which is connected if its zeroth homology is canonically $K.$

Comment: There's a connection between $THH$ and Witt rings and a connection between Witt rings and  Dieudonné modules, so that seems like a good place to start.  There is also a theorem of Goerss relating the  Dieudonné module of $H_*(\Omega^\infty E;\mathbb{F}_p)$ to $E_*(\Omega^2S^3)$.  It would be very valuable to understand that in a more structured way, preferably without recourse to Brown-Gitler technology and apparently-unnatural changes of grading.

Comment: I tried to work with this some years ago but did not get very far.  I struggled with some foundational problems, but they can probably be avoided using $\infty$-categories, which were not available at that point.

Comment: @NeilStrickland I would also like to mention that there is a theory of topological Cartier modules due to [Antieau and Nikolaus](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.01714).

Comment: Thanks for your comments!